# Are there any source APT repositories for Debian Lenny?

Tags: debian

Debian Lenny, the current oldstable, ceased receiving security updates early in February, and now seems to no longer be hosted at the usual FTP mirrors (see, e.g., `curl http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/ | less`).

Are there any surviving FTP repositories of Lenny that can be used via APT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As answered at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/373369/139457) or more verbose at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/404816/116326),
you need to use now [archive.debian.org](http://archive.debian.net/):

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib main non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main
```

To get the GPG key:

```
apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```